# How to use AJAX tabcontainer in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajaxcontroltoolkit, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to use AJAX tabcontainer in asp.net mvc 4. I found out that the AJAX Control Toolkit controls are server controls and are not supported in ASP.NET MVC. But I want to use it.

So please guide to me how can I use tabcontainer with other ways like ajax tabcontainer.

Comment: you cannot. you need to think about it in a different approach. remember, ASP.NET MVC is different than ASP.NET. What are you trying to do here? Thought about using pure JQuery/javascript libraries? After all, that is what most of the AJAX controls are based upon (pure javascript)

Comment: what should I do?? If do so, what tabcontainer  can I use in mvc.

Comment: MVC does not have server side controls. As I said, look at popular javascript frameworks that have such a control or make your own. This really is not a specific server side question but more a client side UI development question.